# $cordovaStatusbar - Android - ionic status bar appearing when app brought to the foreground

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I use the $cordovaStatusbar plugin to hide the top status bar when my app is launched. It works as expected -- except for Android (app opens with no status bar as expected) - but when the app is put in the background (or the phone goes to sleep) - and then brought to the foreground, the status bar is there and stays there.

I have tried reissuing the $cordovaStatusBar.hide() command again when the app recognizes it has been brought to the foreground but that doesn't work. The status bar is on the top and obscuring my header.

Is there a trick to make it go away again?

Answer (score 0):

This issue went away on its own, tho I did invoke the hide() method whenever the app resumed.